# Upload sqlite file to provisioned iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data

I have successfully downloaded an sqlite datafile from my testing app on my provisioned iPhone using the Xcode organizer. How might I upload an sqlite file to the iphone to replace the data store that I am using in my app?

Comment: -1 You need to provide some more detail. Is this just for development or are you wanting to replace a DB on the user's device after the app ships? Are you replacing a readonly DB that ships with the app? Are you replacing a writable DB generated by the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently discovered the answer to this question: You can just include the relevant SQLite file in your app bundle, and copy the file onto the location of the actual SQLite file which Core Data uses for its data store.

Answer (score 1):

You can't upload a file after installation in the same way that you can download it in the Organizer.

If you want to get a data file into the app, add it to your project's resources and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the contents of a file on your iPhone, you can use the Organizer to Upload the file from your Mac to your iPhone. First use the Organizer to download the file from your iPhone to your Mac by clicking Download. Copy the file you want upload from your Mac to your iPhone into the <...>.xcappdata/AppData/Documents/ directory. Next click Upload. Then restart your app to read in the contents of the updated file. That's it!